# What happens with 100% reduction of control impairing effects?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does this grant immunity to status effects such as stun, charm, freeze, fear etc? Also, is this achievable?

Comment: I doubt it's achievable, and it probably does grant immunity if you can achieve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it once with my monk for the fun of it, and sold the equipment later on.

The gear had approx. 81% reduction in total, plus the [Perseverance](http://www.diablowiki.net/Perseverance) rune on my [Mantra of Evasion](http://www.diablowiki.net/Mantra_of_Evasion).

What happens? The frozen/jailed animation kicks in for a moment, and you are free a millisecond after that. Although, this was pre 1.03 patch. I don't know if they changed this behaviour afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This is mainly to point out post-1.0.3 changes which bora didn't cover in his post; I haven't done any testing on 100% CC reduction - hopefully bora or someone else gives us more details.*

From the [patch 1.0.3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/Patch_103_Now_Available-6_19_2012) notes:

> Crowd Control Reduction from items and skills will now reduce the percentage value of Slow, Chill, and Attack Speed debuffs rather than reducing how long the debuff lasts
>
> For example: previously, if you were debuffed by a 60% slow that lasted for 2 seconds while wearing gear that provides 20% Crowd Control Reduction, your movement speed would be reduced by 60%, but only for 1.6 seconds. Now, the same amount of Crowd Control Reduction will reduce the Slow effect to 48%, but the effect will remain for the full 2 second duration.

As they specifically mention chilled, I imagine it works as described for Frozen - no idea if Jailed also means you get to drag along the jail at half speed, if you have 50% reduction.

Comment: No, for absolute effects like Jailer it still reduces the time.  But the question was specifically about what 100% does, which you don't address at all.

Comment: True, I should've mentioned that this was more a response to Bora's post - couldn't include the changes in a comment under it, so I had to post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

well, just tried building "max gear" for CC-redux
In short: You are not  able to get 100%.

When you have the cap (108% from gear) it stacks like so:
Helm= 14% redux, multiplier = .86
Neck= 14% redux, multiplier = .86 
Ring (left) = 14% redux, multiplier = .86 
Ring (right) = 14% redux, multiplier = .86 
Wrist = 4% redux, multiplier = .96
etc.
it ends up to be following calculation:
1-(.86*.86*.86*.86*.96* ... ) = reduction by 68.56 (rounded - the Details window in game shows 68.55)

Anyway, since no single item has 100% reduction, you can't get 100% reduction.

So to answer your question, here's what I think would happen - game would crash :)

Comment: I don't think your conclusion is correct.